# C# getting data from MDB and putting results into a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a .MDB file that has a n_groups table, and three columns I need to reference, those being NUID, strName and ntype.  The query works as intended, however the listbox just appears empty with no results.

How can I make the results populate a listbox?

This is what I have so far:

```
var conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
    "data     source=C:\\menus\\newmenus\\menu.mdb;Jet " + 
    "OLEDB:Database Password=@#@#@#");

var ds = new DataSet();
var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(
    "SELECT nUID, strName FROM n_groups where ntype=1", conn);
conn.Open();
adapter.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
var value = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["strName"].ToString();

listBox1.DataSource = value;
```

Say I wanted to reorder the list using a second list box (like a picklist sorter) is there a way to call the position of an item within a listbox?

I need to be able to re order the contents of the results from top to bottom for sorting.

I was going to use a picklist sorting method like this :
[image: demo picklist sorter]

But I can't get the left list to populate.  How do I use C# to get data from MDB and put the results into a listbox?

Comment: For one thing, I think you are closing your connection object prematurely. You also to need to read up on the DataSource object. It is used to bind the control to a data source, you can't set it to a string value as you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an easier way to do it... instead try it this way

```
How can I make the results populate a listbox?
```

This is semi-psuedocode:

```
dt DataTable
dt =  ds.Tables[0]
listbox1.datasource = dt
listbox1.datamember = "nameoffield"
listbox1.databind()
```

This basically takes the entire datatable and binds it to the control. You can reference each object with `.SelectedIndex` or `.SelectedItem`

I think what you are trying to look for is this:

in the click event of add:

```
listbox2.items.add(listbox1.selecteditem)
```

In the click event of remove

```
listbox2.items.removeat(listbox2.selectedindex)
```

Comment: note that the listbox properties are case sensitive and without an editor in front of me I dont remember the exact casing

Comment: hey that worked great!! there be info in my listBox. now to wrap my head around the silly picklist sorter thing

Comment: So @ShaneSuperflyMacNeill what are you trying to achieve with the right side thats not working.

Comment: well the values on the left represent columns in the database. currently they are used in an application that displays them in the order they appear in the database. However there is no way to reorder the columns to group them better. The idea is to 1: show the current order which is on the left, then using the "arrows" be able to push them to the right box in the new order, like picking. then hitting an update button that will re write the order to the database using the new order on the right. I just can't seem to wrap my head around how exactly to do it.

Comment: that helped big time, one question. in a list box, is there any kind of assigned value that is given to an item in a list? like the first item in the list is 1 for instance and the third one down is 3, or do we need to assign those as well? Thank you for all your help it's like 10pm here and i would love to get out of the office. I have never built one of these before.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33239/discussion-between-shane-superfly-macneill-and-logixologist)

Comment: Sorry it will have to be later today for the chat because its blocked from my work.